# Can't install Latest mongodb On Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS xenial

Tags: 16.04, mongodb

I am trying to install the latest version of mongodb (which is currently 3.6)  by following official documentation given [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) . But it always install version 2.6. Specific version install also not working

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have run an old process
You may revert what you have done and follow the community edition instructions customized for 3.6
According to the [MongoDB community edition documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/)

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 0C49F3730359A14518585931BC711F9BA15703C6
echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.6 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.6.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

Comment: Now Getting E: Unable to locate package mongodb-org
 error. Done the all steps

Comment: any error while running the 3 first steps ?

Comment: No, Everything works fine. created new mongodb-org-3.6.list
 in /etc/apt/sources.list.d with this line 

deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.6 multiverse

Comment: search the package name with `apt-cache policy mongodb*` -- should be mongodb-org...

Comment: NoI have removed all previous mongodb keys and now repeated the same steps. now getting this on apt-get update

Comment: W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.6 Release:

Comment: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 58712A2291FA4AD5
W: Failed to fetch http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/xenial/mongodb-org/3.6/Release.gpg  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 58712A2291FA4AD5
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: I am following documentation of 3.6

Comment: Same problem, following a bunch of tutorials with no joy.